# Extracting a value from AngularJS and storing it in a javascript variable

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angularjs. Here is a few lines of code from a **.cshtml** file. The angularjs objects in the `<label>` element get resolved and display correctly. That is, they display the actual address: 275 Americoan Ave, etc. The same angularjs objects in the second line from the bottom do not get resolved. The alert function displays the line as `"{{ qc.SubjectAddress }},{{..."`. Can someone explain to me the correct way to get the address out of the angularjs expression and assign it to a variable? Thanks.

```
<label id="address" name="address">{{ qc.SubjectAddress }},{{ qc.SubjectCity }}, {{  qc.SubjectState }}  {{ qc.SubjectZip }}</label>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div id="compMap"></div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var address = '{{ qc.SubjectAddress }},{{ qc.SubjectCity }}, {{  qc.SubjectState }}  {{ qc.SubjectZip }}';
                    alert(address);
```

Comment: Put that code in the controller, not in the template. The template is for HTML code. The controller is for JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable address is in a different slope that the one outside the `<script>` tags.

To make it work you don't need the `<script>` tags. Only make sure you have the controller declared using the `ng-controller` on the right slope.

After that, all the code can go inside de `{{}}`.

You can use your logic on your controller like this:

```
var address = SubjectAddress + ',' + SubjectCity + ',' +  SubjectState +   SubjectZip ;
```

And then:
`{{qc.address}}` on your HTML

Or writing the code directly on your view like this (Without the `<script>` tags:

```
{{ qc.SubjectAddress +','+ qc.SubjectCity ',' +  qc.SubjectState  + ' ' qc.SubjectZip }}
```

For better practice I recommend the first method, since it keeps the HTML more clean and easy to read.

Comment: Thanks. That was very helpful.

Comment: Good to know that it was helpful :) Upvoting would make really helpful for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to go back and look through some controller tutorials. Normally you'd want a function like that inside a controller.

Here specifically, the answer is that `<script>` tags get ran all at once before anything in Angular will fire off. This loads up all of Angular's configuration. Then Angular will run through its constants, values, configs, providers, services, directives, and controllers (in that order). Only *then* will Angular fill in the `{{ }}` HTML braces.

So, in short, run your `alert()` inside the controller for the page that you're trying to run this on.